# I want to write a servlet which supports https connection

Tags: servlets, https

I want to write a servlet which supports https connection. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do anything different when creating the servlet to support HTTPS.

You do, however, have to change your application server to accept HTTPS requests. For example, with Tomcat you'd do this by [creating an HTTPS connector in server.xml](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support).

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should not need to change your servlet, you should be able to deploy it to an app-server serving the page over HTTP or HTTPS. All the work you will have to do is in configuring your application server. Assuming you are using Tomcat, the following link should explain - http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/ssl-howto.html